# Angular: Cors error when sending a particular request to my PHP server. But the same requests works everywhere else

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, fastcgi

I have an ec2 instance running nginx.

Here is my nginx config:

```html
`    server {
      listen       443 ssl;
      root         /var/www/angular/dist/testenpoint-website-angular;
      index        index.htm index.html;
      server_name  www.testenpoint.com;
      client_max_body_size 100m;
    
      location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    
    location /applicationApis/ {
      root /var/www/html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
    }
    
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }
    
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/testenpoint-all/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/testenpoint-all/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    }
    
    server {
    if ($host = testenpoint.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    
    
    if ($host = www.testenpoint.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    
    
    listen      80;   #listen for all the HTTP requests
    server_name testenpoint.com www.testenpoint.com;
    return      301         https://www.testenpoint.com$request_uri;
    
    }
    
    server {
    if ($host = testenpoint.co.uk) {
    return 301 https://www.testenpoint.com$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    
    
    if ($host = www.testenpoint.co.uk) {
    return 301 https://www.testenpoint.com$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    
    
    listen      80;
    server_name testenpoint.co.uk *.testenpoint.co.uk;
    return      301         https://www.testenpoint.com$request_uri;
    
    
    }
    server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  testenpoint.co.uk *.testenpoint.co.uk;
    return       301         https://www.testenpoint.com$request_uri;
    }`
```

I am calling this via my angular application like so:

```
https://www.testenpoint.com/applicationApis/getPdfReport.php
```

With the request is send auth header and in the body a few params. One param is called 'filterObject' this is a string object. When this is empty the request is fine. When I send stuff in there via my angular application I have a 404 response. Via postman, no issues. Via my test instance no issues.

This error appears in my nginx logs when this happens:

```
2023/01/03 19:28:50 [error] 24875#0: *42 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: www.testenpoint.com, request: "POST /applicationApis/getPdfReport.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "www.testenpoint.com", referrer: "http://localhost:4200/"
```

and

```
2023/01/03 19:28:50 [error] 24875#0: *42 open() "/var/www/angular/dist/my-website-angular/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: www.testenpoint.com, request: "POST /applicationApis/getPdfReport.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock", host: "www.testenpoint.com", referrer: "http://localhost:4200/"
```

I am wondering if anyone can help here?

Also to note the the PHP code actually runs as I can see the logs etc all the way to completion. But all I get is a 404 even though my PHP code is showing no error. I believe it is an Nginx config issue and its only happening on this instance with this config and not my test instance with a slightly different config

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this into your server block:

```
server {
 proxy_busy_buffers_size   512k;
 proxy_buffers   4 512k;
 proxy_buffer_size   256k;
}
```

Comment: Still the same issue unfortunately. Its very weird as of the formatObject has multiple stringed objects it works. But if 1 alone object it doesn't